# Как выбрать все элементы с классом X, но без класса Y (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно получить все элементы с классом class, у которых отсутствует класс extraClass, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.class:not(.extraClass)').each(function(){
  ...
});
```